# How to change the value of wxDatePickerCtrl?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have tried this, But I am not able to get date displayed on the datePickerCtrl.

Here SDOB is a wxDatePickerCtrl.

```
SDOB->SetValue(Rs.GetDate(3));
```

But I am able to get the date onto a label or text field by doing

```
wxStaticText11->SetLabel(Rs.GetDate(3).FormatDate());
```

But for my purpose I would like to get it onto the datePickerCtrl itself. Help!

Also where can I find good documentation with examples for wxWidgets? I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the correct function for setting `wxDatePickerCtrl` value, so if you don't see what you expect, the date you pass to it must be invalid or otherwise different from what you think it is. Generally speaking, when asking about why something doesn't work you should explain both how do you expect it to work and what actually happens because otherwise nobody else can know what's really going on.

The documentation for this control is at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_date_picker_ctrl.html as could be expected and there are a hundred of examples distributed with wxWidgets, so if you want to see an example of this class in action, I recommend doing `grep -lR wxDatePickerCtrl samples` in the directory containing wxWidgets sources.

Good luck!

Comment: My purpose is to display the date onto the datePickerCtrl itself. The date I passed to it was collected from datePickerCtrl. In documentation under SetValue it says "Calling this method does not result in a date change event.". Does this mean I can't display mydate to datePickerCtrl? Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you actually tried executing the code? It does change the value _displayed_ in the control. What the documentation tells you is that it does not generate an event for it, unlike in the case of the user entry, but this doesn't mean at all that the display is not updated.